# Something about moving shapes around in Canvas in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, shapes

I have a rectangle which want to move using `Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);`

But I wanna make it look like a smooth transition (animation). Here's the code snippet that's supposed to do this:

```
void animate()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
        {
            MainWindow.current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(move));
            x += 10;
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void move()
    {
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    }
```

It seems very basic but I'm having trouble doing it. I want the thread to sleep for a little time, & then set the rectangle's x to a new value. But instead, the thread sleeps for `30*10` milli seconds, then the rectangle moves right instantly by 10*10 units. I'm not able to get the animation effect I want. And I'm aware that I've called `Sleep` on the GUI thread but I don't think that should affect the animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of forcing your UI thread to sleep. I would suggest you to use the `Storyboard Animation` provided by WPF specially for this purpose. This link will get you started if its's something new too you -

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/12/28/wpf-simple-animations-to-move-and-resize-elements-simultaneously.aspx

Comment: I'm going to be solving a maze defined by the user graphically. So will using StoryBoard animation be efficient for moving the block around? coz I want to move it in any direction I want to, increase speed, & so on..(I wanna have full control over my block)

Comment: This is what StoryBoard is designed for. It will give you smooth animation atleast better then letting your thread sleep.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be a success. For one thing you have a threading issue, Sleep() on the UI thread blocks screen updates. Using another thread will give poor results at best.

And you don't need this, just learn how to define animations (`<Storyboard />`) in XAML. You can trigger them from C#.

#### Edit

Try and watch this little snippet:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = "Click";
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
    }
```

Comment: I'll try out StoryBoard but can you tell me what threading issue do I have here? The GUI thread does not get blocked & so prevented from updating rectangle's position or does it?

Comment: Why does the label get updated after 2.5 seconds!!? It should update the label's content, THEN sleep for 2.5 secs right???

Comment: Rushil, it demonstrates how updating works in WPF (and WinForms). You need the UI thread to refresh the label.